# Slim API URL showing 404 in wordpress subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, slim

I have installed slim API in a subfolder of wordpress installation. But while accessing slim API via public/index.php it is showing 404 error.

Is there any way to exclude wordpress subfolder from root htaccess?

Thanks